# VMkernal nic doesn't seem available?

Tags: networking, vmware, esxi

We have a two Dell PowerEdge T440's, where one NIC is capable of 1 gigabit so that we can transfer VM's directly between the two quickly.  Using ESXI 7.0.

However, it does not seem to be working how I need it to and I need assistance.  Don't know the best way to describe this so I will just start with the Virtual Switch.

I have three virtual switches setup -
`terminal` - Uplink 1 -  vmnic0, 100 mps, everything else is default settings
`plant` - Uplink 1 - vmnic 1, 100 mps, everything else default
`redundancy`  - Uplink 1 - vmnic3 10000 mbps, everything else default

The `plant` switch has nothing to do with any of this so I will ignore it while I talk about the relevant port groups -
I have 3 port groups for `terminal` vSwitch - `VM Network`, `pgTerminal` and `Management Network`.

The `Management Network is used as a VMkernel Nic with a static IPv4, services set to Management.`  pgTerminal`is used as a network card on my VM's.` VM Network` is unused but was requested to be added.

Now this part works insofar as if I am on a computer on the same network, I can access the ESXI web ui via the VMKernel NIC I setup using my `Management Network` port group, and I can also do some from within my VM's on the server.

The `redundancy` vSwitch has two port groups - `pgRedundancy` and `Backup`.  `pgRedudancy` is used as a network card in our VM's and `Backup` is used as a VMKernel NIC with a static IPv4 ip.

All my VM netowrk cards are setup the same -
Network Card #1 uses `pgTerminal` (all default settings)
Network Card #2 uses `pgPlant` (all default settings)
Network Card #3 uses `pgRedundancy` (all default settings).

Physically, wires from NIC's 0 and 1 go into a switch into a larger network so I can access the Web UI via the `Management Network` VMKernel NIC I setup.  NIC 2 has nothing in it.  NIC 3 has a wire straight from Server 1 to Server 2.

Last two bits of context.  The VM's using the `pgRedundancy` port group for their 3rd network card use a `10.10.10.x` IP with a  `255.255.255.0` subnet.  My VM on Server 1 is able to ping my VM on Server 2 and vice versa over this `10.10.10.x` network.

My other network computer I use to access the ESXI Web UI with the `Management Network` VMKernel NIC (which again the VM's are also able to access) is unable to access the ESXI Web UI via the `Backup` VMKernel NIC via 10.10.10.201 (or .202).  If I plug my laptop directly into NIC 3 with an ethernet and setup my IP correctly I CAN use the ESXI Web UI via 10.10.10.201, but that has been the only way I've successfully done it.

I am at a loss especially because some things seem (like my VM's can see each other over the 10.10.10.x network across Servers) but I cannot see the ESXI web ui or ping that address.  But directly connecting to the port does show it to me.

I must be missing something simple but I am not an ESXI expert in fact this is my first real project with it.

Comment: I can provide any additional details if anyone has any.  I cannot for the life of me figure it out.  I just compared my settings to a system that has this method "working" and everything seems identical (apart from they use all their NICs and I have one empty but they also have one more network).  Just tested again and I can access ESXI web UI via connecting my laptop directly to the server via ethernet but still my VM's or other computers on the network cannot.